Docker-in-Docker: mounting volume from host system not working
I am using DinD by mounting the docker.sock from my host system into my container, using docker-compose.
services:
  dw-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8500:8500"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./uploads:/app/uploads
      - ./db:/app/db
      - ./flask-logging.log:/app/flask-logging.log
      - ./gunicorn-logging.log:/app/gunicorn-logging.log
      - ./flask-config.cfg:/app/flask-config.cfg
    environment:
      - UPLOAD_PATH=/mnt/c/Users/<user>/OneDrive/Dokumente/<company>/docker-workflow-web-app
      #- UPLOAD_PATH=/app
      - FLASK_CFG_PATH=/app/flask-config.cfg
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

Within my program, I am running
HOST_UPLOAD_DIR = os.path.join(os.environ.get('UPLOAD_PATH'), dir_path)

print(HOST_UPLOAD_DIR)


if not zotero_used:
    docker_command = ["docker", "run","--rm", "--volume", f"{HOST_UPLOAD_DIR}:/app/files", "d2md-debug", doc_file_name]
    result = subprocess.run(docker_command)

The d2md-debug container is correctly created, however, the mounted folder in HOST_UPLOAD_DIR is empty, so the files are not found. The thing is, if I run that command on my host system using the same path, everything works just fine. So, I assume this has something to do with the permissions regarding the host file system? But they do all have 777, for the sake of debugging, and they were even created from within the container on the host system by mounting the uploads folder from my host to the container (which works fine, I can create files on my host from within the container via mounting the directory). Another strange thing is that I was using this function/approach a couple of months ago in a slightly different context, and everything worked just fine. I first thought this might have something to do with the fact that the files are currently on Onedrive, but it doesn't work either if I use, for instance, /home/<user>/uploads as mounted directory (using WSL/Ubuntu on Windows 11).
Thank you for your help!
Solution
Update May 2024:
Okay, Docker Desktop Version 4.30.+ seems to have fixed this issue, so the previous fix shouldn't be necessary any longer, see also patch notes:

Fixed a regression in Docker Desktop 4.28 that caused host files bind-mounted into containers to not show up properly inside the container, when using Docker-in-Docker (via mounts of /var/run/docker.sock) on WSL.

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4300
Previous answer/solution:
The problem was solved using DavidMaze suggestion (see the comments): using /c/Users/... instead of /mnt/c/User/.. did the trick (I am using Docker Desktop for Windows).

UPLOAD_PATH=/mnt/c/Users/<user>/OneDrive/Dokumente/<company>/docker-workflow-web-app  shold be something like /app/uploads

Are you sure? This is the path on my HOST, which is where the docker daemon should be running. /app/uploads is the path in my container. The idea is to evoke the docker daemon on my host, and as fasr as I know, this means that I have to use path on my host system. And it worked fine in other contexts. I also tried /app/uploads for the sake of it, and it doesn't work either.

Try to add privileged: true to you so docker-compose file. Also you can try to mount your host path to container. Perhaps it uses your local container filesystem

Are you using Docker Desktop?  That runs containers in a hidden Linux VM.  I think you're correctly expecting the docker run -v source path to be on the host system and not in the container starting it, but "the host system" might be the Linux VM and not the actual physical machine.  This Docker Desktop FAQ suggests the right path might be /c/Users/..., without a leading /mnt?

Thank you, @DavidMaze, this actually solved the issue. <3 I didn't know that and I am still confused since it used to work with the /mnt/... before, but maybe I am overlooking something here. Great thing is that the app is finally deployed on a linux server, so there won't be any issues regarding Docker Desktop.

You've correctly identified that the docker run -v bind-mount option uses a path from "the host system", even if you're running the docker command inside the container.  On Docker Desktop, though, Docker runs inside a hidden Linux virtual machine, and "the host system" for purposes of these bind mounts is that Linux VM.  Docker Desktop can pass through some paths to the real host system but it does need to know about them.
A Docker Desktop FAQ suggests that, on a Windows system, a subset of the C:\ drive is available on a Linux path /c/ in the Docker Linux VM.  If you use /c/Users/... in the UPLOAD_PATH value, rather than /mnt/c/Users/..., this should work.  This is still subject to Docker Desktop's limitations on what paths are visible to Docker, but a path in your own home directory will be visible by default.

They seem to have fixed this in 4.30., see https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4300 Meaning that the initial /mnt/c/... path should work now as expected.
